# Making COD available to only one state

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi so I have this site up. allsocks.com.ng and we're trying to make cash on delivery available only for orders to the base state. I was wondering if I could edit the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27094892/hide-cash-on-delievery-for-orders-over-certain-amount-of-money-in-woocommerce) to fit.

If yes, then what do I edit?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> **Try this**

```
function change_payment_gateway( $gateways ){
$included_states = array( 'AK','HI','GU','PR' ); // add your state here
    // Compare cart subtotal (without shipment fees)
   if(in_array( WC()->customer->shipping_state, $included_states ) ){

      }
 else{
   // then unset the 'cod' key (cod is the unique id of COD Gateway)
    unset( $gateways['cod'] );
    }
    return $gateways;
}
```

Comment: Can I possibly define the conditions based on states to included, rather than the ones to be excluded? So rather than added 35 states to be excluded, I'm add 1 or 2 states that qualify. 

This can help it easy for someone else to update that part of the script without me.

Comment: i have edited my answer according to your requirement , now you will have to add whom COD is available and not exclude

Comment: Neither of them worked. I have it tested here marvelworx.com/worx/allsocks. With only Lagos as the included state