# Hide WooCommerce payment methods for specific shipping zones and min subtotal

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-method

In WooCommerce, I'm trying to remove "Cash on delivery" payment method when cart subtotal is up to $250 for specific shipping zones names (Zone 1, Zone 4 and Zone 7).

All others zones must not have this restriction.

Here is my incomplete code based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27094892/hide-cash-on-delievery-for-orders-over-certain-amount-of-money-in-woocommerce/27095487#27095487):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'change_payment_gateway', 20, 1);
function change_payment_gateway( $gateways ){
    
    $zone = $shipping_zone->get_zone_name();

    if( WC()->cart->subtotal > 250 ) && if($zone=='Zone 1','Zone 4','Zone 7'){
    
        unset( $gateways['cod'] );
    }
    return $gateways;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will remove "Cash on delivery" payment gateway for specific shipping zones and when cart subtotal is up to **`250`**:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'conditionally_remove_payment_methods', 20, 1);
function conditionally_remove_payment_methods( $gateways ){
    // Not in backend (admin)
    if( is_admin() ) 
        return $gateways;

    // HERE below your targeted zone names
    $targeted_zones_names = array('Zone 1','Zone 4','Zone 7');

    $chosen_methods    = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' ); // The chosen shipping mehod
    $chosen_method     = explode(':', reset($chosen_methods) );
    $shipping_zone     = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zone_by( 'instance_id', $chosen_method[1] );
    $current_zone_name = $shipping_zone->get_zone_name();

    if( WC()->cart->subtotal > 250 && in_array( $current_zone_name, $targeted_zones_names ) ){
        unset( $gateways['cod'] );
    }
    return $gateways;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.