# Maximun Order Amount for specific payment method in WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, payment-method

We have to set a maximum order amount for Check payments in WooCommerce, and we don't want to use plugins. But I can't find something suitable, tried some codes and nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Hide cash on delievery for orders over certain amount of money in woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27094892/hide-cash-on-delievery-for-orders-over-certain-amount-of-money-in-woocommerce/27095487#27095487) answer, you can adapt it changing `'cod'` with `'cheque'` payment ID.

For a **maximum** order amount based on cart subtotal *(for specific payment ID(s))*:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways' , 'max_order_amount_for_payment_gateways', 100 );
function max_order_amount_for_payment_gateways( $payment_gateways ){
    if( is_admin() ) {
        return $payment_gateways; // Not in backend (admin)
    }
    
    $targeted_payment_ids = array('cheque'); // Here define the affected payment method IDs
    $threshold_amount  = 100; // Here define the desired subtotal amount threshold 
    $cart_subtotal = WC()->cart->subtotal;

    // Loop through available payment IDs
    foreach ( $payment_gateways as $payment_id => $values ) {
        if( in_array($payment_id, $targeted_payment_ids) && $cart_subtotal >= $threshold_amount ){
            unset($payment_gateways[$payment_id]); // Hide payment method
        }
    }
    return $payment_gateways;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

For a **Minimum** order amount, simply replace 
`$cart_subtotal >= $threshold_amount` 
with 
`$cart_subtotal < $threshold_amount`